# Why does setTimeout with new function ignore wait interval?

Tags: javascript

When trying to do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Boo");}, 500);
```

I accidentally wrote this:

```
setTimeout(new function(){alert("Boo");}, 500);
```

The former version waits 500 millis, then alerts. The latter alerts immediately.

Why does adding `new` in front of the function cause this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `new` creates a new object using the anonymous function as its constructor, so your function runs and alerts immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The latter one instantiates an `Object` and calls its constructor immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
new function(){alert("Boo");}
```

is an equivalent of

```
var temp1 = function(){alert("Boo");};
var temp2 = new temp1();
```

second line as you see invokes your function using temp1 as a constructor.